# "An oak tree grows to huge size"

Tags: articles

Articles can't be used with proper nouns right? So,

> An oak tree grows to huge size (here, oak is a proper noun so why 'an' is used with it?)

A cow has two horns (does article “a” represent a whole class here? As we use: the dog is a faithful animal)

Comment: Articles can work with proper nouns. Oak is not a proper noun. A cow is not a class, but an individual. There is a mistake in every sentence.

Comment: Even some proper nouns can be used with articles (both definite and indefinite) in some cases. Consider "My dream car is _a Lamboghini_", "_The Stratocaster_ is the most famous guitar in the world" or even "Paul Dirac can be thought of as _the Isaac Newton_ of the twentieth century".

Comment: Questions that start with "I know X" or "X, right?" or the like **always** pick an incorrect factoid. This is no exception. As @YosefBaskin points out, it is not true that articles can't be used with proper nouns. Often articles are part of proper nouns, like _The United States of America_

Answer (score 1):

A proper noun is a particular name of a person, place or thing.  They are written with a capital letter.  Articles can be part the proper noun:

> I visited the United States last year.  (the is part of the proper noun)

> I visited Canada last year ("the" is not part of the name of Canada)

It is rare to use "a" with proper nouns, but possible, in hypothetical situations:

> Let us imagine a Canada which never became independent from Great Britain and was part of the UK...

But in your example "oak tree" is a common noun. It is not a proper noun. It is very common for proper nouns to have articles.

And similarly "A cow" is a common noun,  here referring to one cow (but not one particular cow, any single cow)